# Load Tab Pages Name Property and Text Property into List Box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a tab control within it the Tab Pages property which opens the collection of the Tab Control from the Tab Pages property and then I added my tab pages and it was successful

The application I am building is supposed to have a button that retrieves the Tab Pages' Name Property and Text Property in a foreach statement and posted to the Text box

My Problem is Reaching the Tab Control collection that is not accessible in the foreach statement  which is the Tab Pages property that holds the collection so I can populate its members to the list box

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for populating the ListBox with the names of TabPages, then you could try this:

```
var pages = (from TabPage p in tabControl1.TabPages
             select new{ Text = p.Text}).ToList();

listBox1.DataSource = pages;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
```

Comment: I want to display a list of the names of the tab pages using a For Each statement and the TabPages collection contained in the Tab Control

Comment: you want this?
foreach (TabPage p in TabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(p.Text);
            }